# Is there a basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle=\langle [\mathbf{v}]_{\beta}, [\mathbf{w}]_{\beta}\rangle$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Given an inner product product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $F$, $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $F=\mathbb{C}$.

**My Questions**

1. Is there a basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle=\langle [\mathbf{v}]_{\beta}, [\mathbf{w}]_{\beta}\rangle$ for every $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\in V$, where the second inner product is the standard inner product on $F^n$.
2. Which books I can find this theorem? (I believe it is true.)

Comment: Yes, provided that by inner product you mean Hermitian and positive definite. This should be in any linear algebra book that deals with Hermitian forms. The keyword is Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $\beta$ to be an *orthonormal basis*. You can always obtain such basis by using the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Comment: Aha! I see. Thanks.